# UITableView and Core Data tutorials

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I am a beginner at iOS development and I wanted to know if you knew any good tutorials for UITableView and Core Data where you can add your own info more likely to an address book...
Well let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Stanford iOS series of tutorials excellent, and there are episodes for UITableView and Core Data.

http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255

Lectures 10, 11 and 12 would probably be especially helpful to you.